# Widget loading slowly after installing or upgrading in Android4.2

Tags: android, widget, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I added a widget for my application several versions ago. It works well all the time. Recently I received some feedback showing that the widget is loading very slow when the application first installed or upgraded. This problem happened in Nexus and Nexus4(Android 4.2).

I tried to log the action in onReceive of my `AppWidgetProvider`.

Then I found the broadcast , `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED` and  `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE`, was received almost 1 minute after I installed the app.

Is anybody solved this problem